# Multithreading/executor service for invoking REST service in a loop and adding the result to a map

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executorservice, restful-url

I have a spring batch job application. I need to invoke a REST service for a list of IDs. So, I need to call a REST service in a loop. I need to add the result of each ID that I get from the REST service in a map against that ID.

Problem: this is taking a lot of time.

Could you suggest me some ways to optimize the invocation of the REST services multiple times in a loop using some concept of threads/executor service?

Comment: You write "optimize". This implies that you already have something. Show it!

Comment: Depending on the size of the list, you should divide IDs onto threads and wait till the threads finished collecting their data. [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and/or [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) should help you in merging the collected data after the threads finished.

Answer (score 0):

Hi split the file into multiple files. For example split the file to 20 small files. Now create 20 threads and assign each file into each threads. In this situation all the 20 threads will execute in parallel. Now you need to consider certain things.

1. For a best performance you have to check the hardware of your system and based on that only you need to create the number of threads. For example if your system has 10 micro-processor you should have at max 20 threads. Also need to consider the size of memory for of the system whether enough for 20 threads based on memory needs for each of them.
2. How are you going to handle the output from each thread, is there any dependency amongst threads and how to control them? Synchronization of code block etc.

Hope this will help you little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 8 + `RestTemplate`? If you wanted to do the parallelization without having to create your own `ExecutorService`, you might use `parallelStream()` on your list of IDs and let Java manage the `ForkJoinPool` for you, e.g.:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = ... ;
List<Integer> ids = ... ;
Map<Integer, MyDto> dtosById = ids.parallelStream()
        .map(id -> restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl + "?id=" + id, MyDto.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyDto::getId, Function.identity()));
```

If you aren't using Java 8 or you want more control over the thread pooling, then I recommend using [Spring's `@Async` feature](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) and related configuration options instead of creating and/or destroying various `ExecutorService` instances.

Without seeing more of your setup, your code, etc. This is about as close to an answer as I can give you.